# Better way to do a sum of a function including two arrays between limits

Tags: python, sum

I am trying to run a sum between 1 and k (which is 850 incidentally) the sum is the following;

```
I = sum( (e*I(l_i)*l_i/hc)*(l_i+1 - l_i )
```

where e, h and c are constants and l and I are arrays of equal length more than length k. The sum is over i which is the index of each array, running between 1 and k.

This is what I have so far;

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 
import scipy.constants 

e = scipy.constants.e
h = scipy.constants.h
c = scipy.constants.c

I = []

for i in range(1,k):
    I_temp = (e * Flux[i] * WaveL[i])/(h*c) * (WaveL[i+1]-WaveL[i])
    I.append(I_temp)

I_max = sum(I)
```

This works, but is there a quicker, more natural way to do this?

Comment: Is performance actually an issue? Or are you looking for a one liner?

Comment: `sum(((e * Flux[i] * WaveL[i])/(h*c) * (WaveL[i+1]-WaveL[i])) for i in range(1, k))`. This uses a "generator expression" to avoid creating the temp list. Of course, that's hard to read, so you should probably clean it up, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: This is the definition of why one letter variable names are a terrible idea. "The constants I and l are..."

Comment: You don't need a list just to calculate a sum. You could move `e/(h*c)` out of the sum, you could use numpy arrays for Flux and Wave and multiply them directly.

Comment: @bendl: `e`, `h` and `c` are physical constants. ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil I am aware, but mathematics only uses single letter variables (as far as I am aware) to avoid confusion between multiplication and variable names. Since that confusion doesn't exist here better to use the actual names of the constants.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple optimization possibilities. I assume all vectors are Numpy objects.

1. move `e/(hc)` out of the sum
2. replace `WaveL[i+1]-WaveL[i]` by `numpy.diff`
3. use `numpy.dot` to calculate the inner products of vectors (you'll need two calls)

Numpy is going to be much more efficient than the explicit loop.